# Are the variance and the squared deviation similar?

Tags: variance, definition

I am confused about the difference between the variance and the Squared deviations from the mean. Are they similar? or what is the difference between them?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Please tell us what, exactly, you mean by "squared deviation".  The variance is the square of the standard deviation.

Comment: @PeterFlom It's the Squared deviations from the mean

Comment: The variance is the average of those squared deviations.

Comment: Do you mean the usual variance estimator with $n-1$ in the denominator versus the estimator with $n$ in the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

> The variance is the average of those squared deviations.

– dbwilson